# std::array<float, 4> to std::array<double, 4> casting

Tags: c++

Is it possible to cast a `std::array<float, 4>` to `std::array<double, 4>`?

for example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d62b3846618e4f81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function for it: <kbd>[live sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c72914cab321f64d)</kbd>

```
template<typename Dest, typename Src, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto convert_array_to_impl(const std::array<Src, N> &src, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array<Dest, N>{{static_cast<Dest>(src[Is])...}};
}

template<typename Dest, typename Src, std::size_t N>
auto convert_array_to(const std::array<Src, N> &src) {
    return convert_array_to_impl<Dest>(src, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
...
auto double_array = convert_array_to<double>(float_array);
```

The advantage of this function implementation over a loop is that it will work when the destination type is not default-constructible. If this will never be the case, the loop in the other answer is a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot cast one to the other.  They are two unrelated types.  You need to loop through the source array and set each corresponding element in the destination array.

```
std::array<float, 4> float_array{ 0.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f };

std::array<double, 4> double_array;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < float_array.size(); ++i)
    double_array[i] = float_array[i]
```

Comment: Is it possible to overload the casting operator to do the copying for me?

Comment: @mmostajab You cannot overload the casting operator.  You could write a function to hide the loop.

Comment: @mmostajab That works.  You could template it to make it more generic.  You could also use the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37305009/4342498) provided by [chris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) which looks very good.

Answer (score 0):

The types are not the same, thus you can't merely cast one type to another.

You can use the `std::copy` algorithm function instead of the loop.

```
#include <algorithm>
//..
std::array<float, 4> f4;
std::array<double, 4> d4;

//.. float to double
std::copy(f4.begin(), f4.end(), d4.begin()); 

// double to float
std::copy(d4.begin(), d4.end(), f4.begin());
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant use `std::copy`.